# How to submit the form in focus

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Have you seen facebook comment box? I am trying to make a very similar comment box with textareas. for that I have many forms in my page beneath "wall posts". Each form has a class of `comment-form` and inside that form I have textarea for comment. each of those textarea has a class of `comment-textarea`.

I want to submit a comment on enter. for that I have a javascript

```
$('.comment-textarea').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey){

    } else if(e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.comment-form').trigger('submit');
    }

});
```

but since i have many forms in the page, I don't know how to submit the form which is on focus.

Comment: You have `event.target`, you could find the parent `form`.

Comment: the event object should have the source of the event in it somewhere. .originalTarget or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There 2 solutions. Solution 1 give every form a unique ID so you can target it. Use the comment-textarea to find the form like this :

```
$('.comment-textarea').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey){

    } else if(e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.comment-form').trigger('submit');
    }

});
```

This will find the first parent with the class "comment-form"

Comment: Your first solution don't apply because those posts are created dynamically just like facebook. I don't have static number of posts. Anyway your second solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.closest()`:

```
$(this).closest('.comment-form').trigger('submit');
```

The function `.closest()` goes up one level (like `.parent()`) to see if the class `.comment-form` exists there, and if it doesn't find it, it repeats the process another level up, and again and again until it finds something (if there's anything to find at all).

Comment: closest and parent, both worked.Which one gives the best performance and works on largest set of browsers. Sorry, I am very new to javascript and jquery.

Comment: It doesn't matter - both work equally well. You would have to use `closest()` if you had a nested sort of form, i.e. `<form><div><textarea></textarea></div></form>`. In this case, `parent()` would only go "up" to the level of the `div`, and `closest()` would go up all levels until it finds the level with the appropriate class. (Hope that made sense.) If you don't have nested forms though, it doesn't matter which one you choose.